# Add null values to Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to build the series of data for highcharts to plot my graph.

My array needs to read as YaxisValuesArray = [null, 78.12,null, null, null] - ;
instead my array is [,78.12,,,] because of which my graph is not coming up.

Below is my code

```
 var n = parseInt(releaseprod);
                if (!isNaN(n)) {

                    var number = parseFloat(releaseprod);
                    if (number > 0)
                        YaxisValuesArray.push(parseFloat(releaseprod).toFixed(2));
                    else
                        YaxisValuesArray.push(parseInt(releaseprod));
                }
                else {
                    releaseprod = null;
                    YaxisValuesArray.push(releaseprod);

                }
                 YaxisValuesArray.join(" , ");
```

Though I am explicity pushing the null value to the array. My alert still reads it as  [,78.12,,,].

Highchart code : just for series

```
  series: [{
            showInLegend: true,
            name: 'Values',
            data: YaxisValuesArray //[,78.1,,,] --- NOt able to plot the graph
            //data: [null, 78.1, null, null, null]  -- Able to plot the graph


        }]
```

Someone please tell me how to add null values to the array so that my graph comes up.

Comment: Are you sure that Highchart accepts the data as a string?

Comment: `YaxisValuesArray.join(" , ");` won't convert `YaxisValuesArray` to string, you need to assign the return value of `join()`: `YaxisValuesArray = YaxisValuesArray.join(',');`. THough looks like you'd need an array of numbers here...

Comment: I've created a fiddle and using your data works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/4GkS5/

Comment: @ComFreek, they are not strings ...they are values

Comment: @Janet What do you mean by 'values'? Highcharts accepts its data as an array, see the API documentation: [series.data](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data).

Comment: I am doing YaxisValuesArray.push(parseFloat(releaseprod).toFixed(2));
which ar decimal values

Comment: @ComFreek, if I put my values as data: [null, 78.1, null, null, null] , I get the graph only when I change it to YaxisValuesArray , the graph does not come up(the values will be dynamic) ..

Comment: The alert is probably doing a toString, and converting null to nothing, so it is misleading you. Try doing a console.log(JSON.stringify(YaxisValuesArray));

Answer (score 0):

The `.join()` function returns a string from the array.

The HighChart data parameter is supposed to take in an array of values, with null evaluating to no data at that point.

To fix your issue, simply get rid of the join function call and pass in the YaxisValuesArray array.

Comment: I thought the same first, but he does not reassign the return value from the join operation to `YaxisValuesArray`, so the original array shouldn't be modified.

Comment: @Tim, I removed the .join function but still no luck

Comment: Can you verify the format of YaxisValuesArray in Highcharts series?

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes for you:

- `.toFixed(x)` returns string, so don't use it, or after that one use `.parseFloat()` again
- don't use `join()`, as it returns string
- your code is incomplete. How `releaseprod` variable looks before parsing? How do you loop through all points from backend? Something like this: `[,78.12,,,]` looks really wrong. Also how did you defined `YaxisValuesArray` variable?